# Algorithms that are similar to Dynamic TIme Warping

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, dynamic-programming, signal-processing

Dynamic time warping (DTW) is an algorithm in time series analysis for measuring similarity between two temporal sequences which may vary in time or speed. Here are some explanations of DTW:

1. [Dynamic Time Warping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) by Wikipedia
2. [Dynamic Time Warping](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9783540740476-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-452103-p173751818) by M Müller (2007)

Is there any algorithm that can replace DTW for measuring similarity between two temporal sequences which may vary in time or speed?